# How to detect MarkerView click in native Android Mapbox map?

Tags: android, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

This Mapbox code is now deprecated:

```
mapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new MapboxMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {

        // Show a toast with the title of the selected marker
        Utilities.makeToast(requireContext(), marker.getTitle());
        return true; // Prevents standard InfoWindow from being displayed
    }
});
```

The [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/9.5.0/index.html) says to use the [Mapbox Annotation Plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation) instead. I've read that and have also checked out the [MarkerView example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/marker-view-plugin/) but no clues anywhere on how to detect when a marker (`MarkerView`) has been clicked.

Also, the `MarkerViewManager` and `MarkerView` classes don't seem to have any methods available for detecting marker clicks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a `MarkerView`, you supply a custom view to the constructor, e.g.,:

```
MarkerView markerView = new MarkerView(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), customView);
mMarkerViewManager.addMarker(markerView);
```

So, to get the marker click event, you first call:

```
customView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Utilities.makeToast(requireContext(), "Marker clicked!");
    }
});
```